# Can I style only a specific part of an html input's string value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Can I style just part of an input's value?

Like in this following example (snippet below), can I style just the "@user" part in bold and let the "some other content" unaltered?

[image]

If that's not possible, I'm thinking of using a `div` with `contexteditable`. It's a different approach, but would it work?

```js
function App() {
  const [value,setValue] = React.useState('@user some other content...');
  
  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }
  
  return(
    <input 
      style={{width:'300px'}}
      type='text'
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Form controls accept text only. Styling parts of a string requires html

Comment: So, not possible at all?

Comment: Not possible in an input...but possible in elements that accept html. Wrap parts of string with spans `Start of string <span style="color:red">substring</span>`

Comment: Thank you! If you want to write that as an answer I would gladly accept it here. I'll go with the `div` with `contenteditable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form controls render text only. Styling parts of a string requires html

You would need to wrap parts of string to style in `<span>`

```
Start of string <span style="color:red">substring to style</span>
```

and put it in an html containing element